# EPiServer InitializationException

Tags: episerver

I seem to have run into to a wall that I can't get passed. I have moved an Episite to IIS 7.5 from IIS 6 and also upgraded from cms 5 to 6. I now get the following exception when I start it. I am certain that there is something missing in my web.config but I can't for the *** of it figure out what it is. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       at EPiServer.Configuration.Settings.get_Instance()
       at EPiServer.UriSupport.get_InternalUIUrl()
       at EPiServer.UriSupport.get_UIUrl()
       at EPiServer.UriSupport.ResolveUrlFromUIBySettings(String path)
       at EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.get_CurrentPrincipal()
       at EPiServer.Security.VirtualRolePrincipal.VirtualRolePrincipal_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Was the upgrade successful? What happens if you run the upgraded site on IIS 6? Did you take a backup of the DB and source before the upgrade? You could try doing one thing at a time and seeing where it breaks.

Comment: Yeah everything went well with the upgrade. I believe I know what is wrong now. Will update tommorrow I just need to verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the `<scanAssembly forceBinFolderScan="false">` in the EpiServerFramework.config with specified files to load doesn't seem to work. Debugging with reflector showed that it didn't load any modules at all. Changing to true fixed the problem.

Still no idea why it doesn't load the specified ones tho.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution the change scanAssembly settings to **True**.

```
<scanAssembly forceBinFolderScan="false">
```

This solution wasn't effective to me. I fixed my problem fixed when I was able convert my web.config to works with IIS7.

The solution was exec in CMD with admin privileges the command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/"
```

A trick here is use / at the end of the name of website.